# Why wont the KDE Login Show Up?

Tags: kde

Why is the Unity Login still on ubuntu if I installed KDE Plasma overlay on it. I've gone through all the settings and cant get it to not use unity. When I go to the login screen it remembers that I want KDE Plasma. I really like the KDE login. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install kdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm
  ```

Comment: Newer KDE versions now use lightdm to.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. From Terminal it would be `sudo cp /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.bak`

Then open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with your favorit texteditor and change the line

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

to

```
greeter-session=lightdm-kde-greeter
```

If something breaks with that log into a tty and change the files back.